# Lost information during dimensionality reduction using umap

Tags: python, machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, runumap

I am working with [spotify tracks database](https://www.kaggle.com/zaheenhamidani/ultimate-spotify-tracks-db) and trying to understand how columns danceability, liveness and energy affect popularity (use discrete popularity: -1, 0, 1). I want to do dimensionality reduction from three columns to two. Here's the snippet:

```
reducer = umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=10, min_dist=0.1)
X_reduced = reducer.fit_transform(X)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.title('Projecting %d-dimensional data to 2D' % X.shape[1])
plt.scatter(X_reduced[:, 0], X_reduced[:, 1], c=y, edgecolor='none', s=20,
            cmap=ListedColormap(['yellow', 'red', 'green']))
plt.colorbar(ticks=range(3), label='popularity value')
plt.show()
```

But this code shows me data where popular and unpopular tracks are identical (picture 1) while I need to get data with 3 different clusters (picture 2).
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEPaG.png)
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4iXL.png)

I think that the problem can be in umap parameters or maybe it is bad clusterization task. I tried to change it somehow but it didn't work.